# How to redirect in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

So for example we have url:
localhost://menu/men/shoes/nike

So when user types this url in browser i want to redirect him to page localhost://menu/SOMETHINGELSE/shoes/nike

localhost://menu/men/clothes/addidas => localhost://menu/SOMETHINGELSE/clothes/addidas

How can i do this in Laravel?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects This explains it pretty clearly - feel free to post a new question once you run into an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add redirect in your `web.php` route file.

```
Route::redirect('/menu/men/shoes/nike', '/menu/SOMETHINGELSE/shoes/nike');
```

Else you have to handle on a controller basis, imagining something like a `CategoryController.php`.

```
class CategoryController {
    public function view(Category $category) {
        if ($category->slug === 'nike') {
            return redirect('menu/SOMETHINGELSE/shoes/nike');
        }

        ...
    }
}
```